# How can I access a child form's listbox from it's parent?

Tags: c#

I'm working on a quiz playing / creating app that works with a database.
I managed to make a button "Add Question" (on the quiz creation form) to add the question to a ListBox using `((QuizCreationForm)this.Parent).AddQuestionToList(question);`

I wanted so when an item from "questionList" listBox gets selected, it sends that question back to the true/false form, but I can't manage to find out how to do it.

Here's both codes:

```
// QuizCreationForm.cs

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.OleDb;

namespace Quiz_game
{
    public partial class QuizCreationForm : Form
    {
        private string quizType;
        private int quizID;
        string connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=usersdatabase.mdb;Persist Security Info=False;";
        public QuizCreationForm(string quizType)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.quizType = quizType;
            this.quizID = GetNextQuizID();
        }

        List<UserControl> questionControls = new List<UserControl>();
        int currentIndex = 0;
        UserControl questionControl;

        private void QuizCreationForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //if (currentIndex > 0 && currentIndex < questionControls.Count)
            //{
            //    questionControls[currentIndex].Hide();
            //    currentIndex--;
            //    questionControls[currentIndex].Show();
            //}

            questionList.SelectedIndex--;
        }

        public void AddQuestionToList(string question)
        {
            questionList.Items.Add(question);
        }


        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //if (currentIndex < questionControls.Count - 1 && currentIndex >= 0)
            //{
            //    questionControls[currentIndex].Hide();
            //    currentIndex++;
            //    questionControls[currentIndex].Show();
            //}
            questionList.SelectedIndex++;
        }



        private void panel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Panel panel = (Panel)sender;
            int index = (int)panel.Tag;
            questionControls[currentIndex].Hide();
            currentIndex = index;
            questionControls[currentIndex].Show();
        }
        private int GetNextQuizID()
        {
            int quizID = 0;

            using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
            {
                connection.Open();
                string query = "SELECT MAX(QuizID) FROM QuestionTable";
                using (OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(query, connection))
                {
                    // Execute the command and retrieve the result
                    object result = command.ExecuteScalar();

                    // If the result is not null, convert it to an integer and increment it by 1
                    if (result != null && result != DBNull.Value)
                    {
                        quizID = Convert.ToInt32(result) + 1;
                    }
                }
            }

            return quizID;
        }

        private void SaveButton_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);

            try
            {
                connection.Open();
                OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
                command.Connection = connection;
                command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO QuestionTable (QuizID, Question, CorrectAnswer, QuestionType) VALUES (@quizID, @question, @correctAnswer, @questionType)";

                foreach (UserControl control in questionControls)
                {
                    string question = "", correctAnswer = "", questionType = quizType;
                    if (control is FillIn)
                    {
                        question = ((FillIn)control).questionTextBox.ToString();
                        correctAnswer = ((FillIn)control).blankTextBox.ToString();
                    }
                    else if (control is MultipleChoice)
                    {
                        question = ((MultipleChoice)control).questionTextBox.ToString();
                        //  correctAnswer = ((MultipleChoice)control).CorrectAnswer;
                    }
                    else if (control is Text)
                    {
                        question = ((Text)control).Question.ToString();
                        correctAnswer = ((Text)control).Answer.ToString();
                    }
                    else if (control is TrueFalse)
                    {
                        question = ((TrueFalse)control).questionTextBox.ToString();
                        //correctAnswer = ((TrueFalse)control).CorrectAnswer;
                    }

                    command.Parameters.Clear();
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@quizID", quizID);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@question", question);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@correctAnswer", correctAnswer);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@questionType", questionType);
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }

                MessageBox.Show("Quiz questions saved successfully!", "Success", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error saving quiz questions: " + ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
            finally
            {
                connection.Close();
            }
        }

        private void QuizCreationForm_Load_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (quizType == "Multiple Choice")
            {
                questionControl = new MultipleChoice();
            }
            else if (quizType == "Fill in the Blank")
            {
                questionControl = new FillIn();
            }
            else if (quizType == "Text")
            {
                questionControl = new Text();
            }
            else if (quizType == "True/False")
            {
                questionControl = new TrueFalse();
            }

            questionControls.Add(questionControl);
            currentIndex++;
            this.Controls.Add(questionControl);
            questionControl.Location = new Point(310, 0);

            foreach (UserControl control in questionControls)
            {
                Panel panel = new Panel();
                panel.Height = 40;
                panel.Dock = DockStyle.Top;
                panel.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
                panel.Tag = currentIndex;
                panel.Click += new EventHandler(panel_Click);

                Label label = new Label();
                label.Text = $"Question {currentIndex + 1}";
                label.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
                label.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft;
                panel.Controls.Add(label);

                // this.questionList.Controls.Add(panel);
                currentIndex++;
            }
        }

        private void questionList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // MISSING PART
        }

    }
}
```

```
// TrueFalse.cs

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Quiz_game
{
    public partial class TrueFalse : UserControl
    {
        public TrueFalse()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void SetQuestionAndAnswer(string question, bool answer)
        {
            questionTextBox.Text = question;
            Answer1.Checked = answer;
            Answer2.Checked = !answer;
        }


        private void Answer1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Answer1.Checked)
            {
                Answer2.Checked = false;
            }
        }

        private void Answer2_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Answer2.Checked)
            {
                Answer1.Checked = false;
            }
        }

        private void True_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Answer1.Checked = true;
            Answer2.Checked = false;
        }

        //public void setQuestion()
        //{
        //    var parentForm = ((QuizCreationForm)this.Parent);
        //    int index = parentForm.questionList.SelectedIndex;
        //    if (index >= 0)
        //    {
        //        DataRow row = parentForm.quizDataSet.Tables["Questions"].Rows[index];

        //        // Set the question text
        //        questionTextBox.Text = row["Question"].ToString();

        //        // Check the correct answer based on the question type
        //        string questionType = row["Type"].ToString();
        //        switch (questionType)
        //        {
        //            case "TrueFalse":
        //                bool answer = bool.Parse(row["Answer"].ToString());
        //                Answer1.Checked = answer;
        //                Answer2.Checked = !answer;
        //                break;
        //            case "MultipleChoice":
        //                int correctAnswer = int.Parse(row["Answer"].ToString());
        //                radioButton1.Checked = correctAnswer == 1;
        //                radioButton2.Checked = correctAnswer == 2;
        //                radioButton3.Checked = correctAnswer == 3;
        //                radioButton4.Checked = correctAnswer == 4;
        //                answerTextBox1.Text = row["Choice1"].ToString();
        //                answerTextBox2.Text = row["Choice2"].ToString();
        //                answerTextBox3.Text = row["Choice3"].ToString();
        //                answerTextBox4.Text = row["Choice4"].ToString();
        //                break;
        //            case "FillIn":
        //                string correctAnswerString = row["Answer"].ToString();
        //                answerTextBox.Text = correctAnswerString;
        //                break;
        //            case "Text":
        //                // There are no correct answers for text questions, so we don't need to do anything here
        //                break;
        //        }
        //    }
        //}



        private void False_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Answer1.Checked = false;
            Answer2.Checked = true;
        }


        private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string question = questionTextBox.Text; // QUESTION
            bool answer = false;

            if (Answer1.Checked)
            {
                answer = true;
            }
            if (!Answer1.Checked && !Answer2.Checked)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please select an answer.");
                return;
            }

            if (question != "")
            {
                // Add the question to the ListBox
                ((QuizCreationForm)this.Parent).AddQuestionToList(question);

                // TODO: Database stuff here
                // MessageBox.Show("DO SOMETHING");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please enter a question.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tried using

```
TrueFalse trueFalseControl = (TrueFalse)myQuizPanel.Controls.Find("trueFalseControl", true)[0];
trueFalseControl.setQuestion(selectedQuestion, myQuizData.GetAnswer(selectedQuestion));
```

but it didn't work either

Comment: Just "tell" the parent form what to do/show via a method. e.g.  `public void UpdateScore(int NewTotal)`